# invalid release key facebook sdk 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to build an application for android that uses de facebook sdk to login. I have followed the facebook procedures for using the sdk and generating the key hashes. Now when I try to login I keep getting the error invalid keyhash the keyhash:  does not match any stored key hashes. This is weird because I generated my keyhash and registred it by facebook. But this gives me the error. I have tried generating the keyhashes on other ways but this didn't work either. Does anyone know how to fix this. You would help me enormously.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you are signing your app and then getting this error so you need to get the Release key for facebook. There are many ways to get it but one of the easiest way is this:

```
    try {
         PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                           "com.your.package.name", 
                            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
          Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),      Base64.DEFAULT));

                  }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

this will log the release keyhash and put it on your fb Development console. Here you go! 
IMPORTANT: your application must be signed with keystore for this otherwise this will log a debug keyhash. (also put your package name in PackageInfo)

Write this code in your any activity's onCreate and remove it after you get the keyhash.